# Problema para navegar en el navigation drawer

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api

Estoy en un navigation drawer y hago que navegue entre fragment pero cuando cargo un fragment me sale encima del fragment que tengo en el content, que es el fragment que se visualiza cunado abro la aplicacion ¿Hay alguna forma de que no se muestre y muestre solo el fragment que pulso el usuario?

Comment: Hola Álvaro, es importante agregar el código para saber que estas realizando, revisa [ask].

Comment: agrega el codigo xml del content y de un fragment